# My program is crashing because of some strange fread and atof problem. But I have no warnings in the compiler

Tags: c

```
file_input = fopen("data-2.txt", "r");
char* buffer2[20];
fread(&buffer2, sizeof(char*), 20, file_input);
float val = atof(buffer2[0]) - '0';
printf("%f \n", val);
```

I am simplying trying to take float values from a file and save them then print them. But my program crashes with no error. It was giving me an error before saying that I was passing atof a char value instead of a char* so I fixed that and now it crashes.

Comment: Do you ***check the return*** of `file_input = fopen("data-2.txt", "r");` or just pray it succeeded?

Comment: With `char* buffer2[20];` you allocate an array of 20 pointers to char, not an array of char! Modify to `char buffer2[20];` and follow the advices of the other members.

Answer (score 1):

- Use an array of `char`, not an array of *pointers*.
- `atof()` expects a pointer to a *string*.  A *string* requires a *null character*.  Append it to the characters read.
- `"%g"` more useful than `"%f"` to well display all possible `float`.
- Avoid naked magic numbers.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
#define BUFFER2_LEN 20
char buffer2[BUFFER2_LEN + 1];
size_t end = fread(buffer2, sizeof buffer2[0], BUFFER2_LEN, file_input);
buffer2[end] = 0;
float val = atof(buffer2);
printf("%.*g\n", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG, val);
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed the * everywhere and added a & in the atof function. Problem solved.

Comment: "Problem solved." --> perhaps not.  Without a _null character_, calling `atoi()` leads to UB.